# Selecting a random element of series

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to select a random integer from the list below using random.randint but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas, please? The list goes from 0 to 229.

```
list(range(len(cleaned_df.loc[cleaned_df["Drug Regimen"]=="Capomulin"])))
```

Thanks!

Comment: `cleaned_df.loc[cleaned_df["Drug Regimen"]=="Capomulin"].sample().index`?

Comment: Thank you. It worked.

Comment: actually it goes out-of-bounds...

Answer (score 3):

You can use `random.choice`:

```
import random

your_list = list(range(len(cleaned_df.loc[cleaned_df["Drug Regimen"]=="Capomulin"])))

random_number = random.choice(your_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
random.choice(your_list)
```

let's you choose random element from a list.

Comment: This works on a `pd.Series` as well!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`randrange`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange) from the [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) package:

```py
import random

upper_range_limit = len(cleaned_df.loc[cleaned_df["Drug Regimen"]=="Capomulin"])
rnd_number = random.randrange(0, upper_range_limit)
```

> [`random.randrange()` returns] a randomly selected element from range(start, stop, step). This is equivalent to choice(range(start, stop, step)), **but doesn’t actually build a range object.**
> https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange